# Get audio input list in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, audio-recording, input-devices

I'm Developing a voice recording system with the help of USB audio cards. Therefore I need to get the list of audio input devices to a listbox where I can select the audio input device. When I attempt to record, always the default audio device will be used. Im using VB.Net. 
Appreciate your kind help

Thank You

Comment: Can you provide a code sample of how you are recording? Which API you using?

Comment: @YacoubMassad I was able to figure the issue. But Im unable to record the audio from the audio device which i have selected.

Answer (score 1):

I've used below mentioned code and it worked for me

```
Dim objSearcher As New System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_SoundDevice")
Dim objCollection As System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection = objSearcher.Get()

For Each obj As System.Management.ManagementObject In objCollection
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(obj.GetPropertyValue("Caption").ToString())
Next
```